# Assigning a value to a single row for a Pandas DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to reassign a value in a single row of a column in a Pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Here's the DataFrame:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'range_total' : [3000,3000,3000,3000,3000,3000,0,2000,2000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000,1000],
    'high_boundary' : [6,6,6,6,6,6,7,9,9,15,15,15,15,15,15],
    'dist_num' : [1197, 142, 142, 1197, 159, 159, 0, 1000, 1000, 398, 50, 50, 398, 50, 50],
    'round_num_sum' : [2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 2996, 0, 2000, 2000, 996, 996, 996, 996, 996, 996]})
```

In my code I subset the DataFrame for each value of `high_boundary` and find the index(es) of the `test_df` corresponding to the greatest value of `dist_num` (picking the first if tied). For this example, I set the index to:

```
sub_idx = 0
```

I can access the value using this (and other similar versions) code:

```
test_df.ix[(test_df.high_boundary == 6), "dist_num"][sub_idx]
```

that returns:

```
1197
```

But assigning a new value fails:

```
test_df.ix[(test_df.high_boundary == 6), "dist_num"][sub_idx] = 42
test_df.ix[(test_df.high_boundary == 6), "dist_num"][sub_idx]
```

which still returns:

```
1197
```

But:

```
test_df.ix[(test_df.high_boundary == 6), "dist_num"] = 42
test_df.ix[(test_df.high_boundary == 6), "dist_num"]
```

returns:

```
0    42
1    42 
2    42
3    42
4    42
5    42
Name: dist_num, dtype: int64
```

I appreciate any help. This is my first post, because I've always found what I've needed on SO until now. I'm using version 0.14.0.

Comment: Please read [returning a view vs copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) to understand why your code behaves the way it does, essentially you are performing chain indexing which may work. This is not recommended, please follow the suggestions in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you can get copy of (part of) original dataframe `test_df`.

Especially if you select elements using  `[...][...]`

So you changed one value in copy, not in oryginal `test_df`

Try for example this:

```
test_df["dist_num"].ix(test_df.high_boundary == 6)[sub_idx] = 0
```

and you should get expected result.

Comment: This did the trick (thanks!), but raises another question for me: how does the `.ix()`  notation vs. `.ix[]` notation "solve" the chaining problem. I did not find it on the pages linked to by @EdChum or @Joop and a quick Google search for that syntax, didn't reveal anything. Thank you.

Comment: `.ix()` is special function and `.ix[]` is only slicing. With function you can do `.ix(... , copy=False)` with slicing you can't. Function can give you `Indexer` as result and slicing gives you `Series` - print `type( .ix() )` and `type( .ix[] )`

Comment: @Joop and @furas Working on this project again and now I'm getting `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannon be hashed.` when running this: `test_df["dist_num"].ix(test_df.high_boundary == 6)[sub_idx] = test_df["dist_num"].ix(test_df.high_boundary == 6)[sub_idx] + 5`.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problems in past.   Suggest you work though examples at

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

specifically the section 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy  will help you.

The editorial explanation is that if you are chain slicing using df[][]  constructs you frequently are slicing to series 1st and then to values.   it is not feasible for pandas to keep track of your original filters to allow you to write back to the slice.

short answer try using a single operator like ".loc" to do selections that you intend to assign to.

Answer (score 0):

When revisiting this code after a few years, I found that the solution posted above now provides an error (using Pandas version 0.20.1 and Python 2.7.13):
`TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`. In case anyone else has this problem, I've added a solution below.

To update a single element of a subset of a `pd.DataFrame`, the index values from the subset were found and then the index corresponding to desired row was used to select the element to update

```
sub_idx = 0

indices = test_df.loc[test_df.high_boundary == 6,"dist_num"].index
print(test_df.loc[indices[sub_idx],"dist_num"])
# 1197
test_df.loc[indices[sub_idx],"dist_num"] = 0 

print(test_df.loc[indices[sub_idx],"dist_num"])
# 0
```